# Editing XML file content with Python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to use Python to read in an XML file containing some parameter names and values, e.g.

```
   ...
   <parameter name='par1'>
        <value>24</value>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name='par2'>
        <value>Blue/Red/Green</value>
   </parameter>
   ...
```

and then pass it a dictionary with the parameter names {'par1':'53','par2':'Yellow/Pink/Black',...} and corresponding **new** values to replace the old ones in the XML file. The output should then overwrite the original XML file.

At the moment I am converting the XML to a python dictionary and after some element comparison and regular expression handling, writing the output again in XML format.

I am not too happy with this and was wondering whether anyone can recommend a more efficient way of doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion is to use [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) or some other [Python XML parser](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml) rather than using regular expressions.  XML is not a language that can be parsed with regular expressions reliably.  (If you consistently try to parse XML with regular expressions **[bad things happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**)

Comment: I especially recommend lxml.  It includes an etree API which is compatible with xml.etree.Elementree, but also has a number of useful extra features.  It's only possible drawback is that (apparently) it is difficult to install on certain platforms.  I've never had any trouble, but I've heard this complaint a number of times.

Answer (score 1):

[`xml.etree.ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) is much more pythonic than other XML parsers.

An example building a `dict` based on your data:

```
>>> src = """<params>
    <parameter name='par1'> <value>24</value> </parameter>
    <parameter name='par2'> <value>Blue/Red/Green</value> </parameter>
    </params>
    """
>>> tree = ElementTree.XML(src)
>>> dict(((i.attrib['name'], i.find('value').text) for i in tree.getiterator('parameter')))
{'par2': 'Blue/Red/Green', 'par1': '24'}
>>>
```

After changing `dict` values, build a new `ElementTree` using similar methods, and generate an XML file with the [`write`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method.
Note examples in the referenced doc that show how to modify content directly in the `etree` structure. Maybe a `dict` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have read in both your old and new XML files and stored them as dictionaries, then overwriting the old values is easy - use [update()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
dict_old.update(dict_new)
```

This updates the original dictionary with the key/value pairs from `dict_new`, overwriting existing keys. Regular expressions are unnecessary, since you presumably want to only match exact keys.